# flutter buid ipa failed with "Encountered error while archiving for device."

Tags: ios, flutter

I tried to build an ios app and encountered this error: "Encountered error while archiving for device.". The build fails every time after I run flutter clean/pub get or when I pull the code from git. After the 2nd or 3rd trial, It success.

Things I've tried:

1. pub cache repair
2. delete pubspec.lock
3. delete Podfile/Podfile.lock and run pod repo update/pod install

This is the error log

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[34559]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both
    /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f3975160) and
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x11604c2b8).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[34559]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib
    (0x1f39751b0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x11604c308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    2 warnings generated.
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/niwat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blfuxewgtzbxnhaurlzjyzuolwsu/Build/Interme
    diates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/bposStaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-bpos
    Staging-iphoneos/webview_flutter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FlutterWebView.o
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-2.0.12/ios/Classes/FlutterWebView.
    m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/disk_space-0.1.1/ios/Classes/SwiftDiskSpacePlugin.
    swift:53:30: warning: left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Int64', so
    the right side is never used
                    return space ?? 0
                           ~~~~~ ^~~~

    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/disk_space-0.1.1/ios/Classes/SwiftDiskSpacePlugin.
    swift:53:30: warning: left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Int64', so
    the right side is never used
                    return space ?? 0
                           ~~~~~ ^~~~

    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/niwat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blfuxewgtzbxnhaurlzjyzuolwsu/Build/Interme
    diates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/bposStaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-bpos
    Staging-iphoneos/camera.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CameraPlugin.o
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m normal
    armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:596:13:
    warning: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use
    atomic_compare_exchange_strong() from <stdatomic.h> instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, newBuffer, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
                ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:9:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5
    .sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomicDeprecated.h:548:6: note: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
    bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier( void *__oldValue, void *__newValue, void * volatile
    *__theValue );
            ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:806:11:
    warning: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use
    atomic_compare_exchange_strong() from <stdatomic.h> instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(pixelBuffer, nil, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
              ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.8.1+7/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m:9:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5
    .sdk/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomicDeprecated.h:548:6: note: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' has
    been explicitly marked deprecated here
    bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier( void *__oldValue, void *__newValue, void * volatile
    *__theValue );
            ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Reachability/Reachability.m:465:63: warning: cast to
    smaller integer type 'unsigned int' from 'Reachability *' [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                                 NSStringFromClass([self class]), (unsigned int) self, [self
                                 currentReachabilityFlags]];
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope
    ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowse
    r/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:557:13: warning: setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated
    in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue:
                previousStatusBarStyle)!
                ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope
    ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope
    ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin,
    SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Types/URLCr
    edential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to 'nil' always
    returns true
            if certificates != nil {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    86:25: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
    'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                    return .spotlightSuggestion
                            ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    86:25: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                    return .spotlightSuggestion
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    121:31: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
    'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                                  ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    121:31: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    216:21: warning: immutable value 'j' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
                    for j in ipv6.count...8 {
                        ^
                        _
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope
    ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/InAppBrowse
    r/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:557:13: warning: setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated
    in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue:
                previousStatusBarStyle)!
                ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope
    ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope
    ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewC
    ontroller/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin,
    SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Types/URLCr
    edential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to 'nil' always
    returns true
            if certificates != nil {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    86:25: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
    'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                    return .spotlightSuggestion
                            ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    86:25: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                    return .spotlightSuggestion
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    121:31: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
    'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                                  ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    121:31: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Util.swift:
    216:21: warning: immutable value 'j' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
                    for j in ipv6.count...8 {
                        ^
                        _
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.sw
    ift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject'
    instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                       ^~~~~
                                                       AnyObject
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.sw
    ift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject'
    instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                     ^~~~~
                                                     AnyObject
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.sw
    ift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject'
    instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                       ^~~~~
                                                       AnyObject
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.sw
    ift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject'
    instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                     ^~~~~
                                                     AnyObject
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FileUtils.m:129:30:
    warning: unused variable 'exportError' [-Wunused-variable]
                        NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:1
    03:125: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id _Nullable' to parameter of
    type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') [-Wint-conversion]
            [self resolvePickMedia:[FileUtils resolveMediaType:call.method]
            withMultiPick:isMultiplePick withCompressionAllowed:[arguments
            valueForKey:@"allowCompression"]];
                                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                            ~~~
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:1
    43:102: note: passing argument to parameter 'allowCompression' here
    - (void) resolvePickMedia:(MediaType)type withMultiPick:(BOOL)multiPick
    withCompressionAllowed:(BOOL)allowCompression  {
                                                                                            ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:2
    25:68: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum
    UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPreset' to different enumeration type 'enum
    DKImageExportPresent' [-Wenum-conversion]
            exportConfiguration.imageExportPreset = allowCompression ?
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCompatible :
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCurrent;
                                                  ~
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                  ~
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:2
    25:124: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum
    UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPreset' to different enumeration type 'enum
    DKImageExportPresent' [-Wenum-conversion]
            exportConfiguration.imageExportPreset = allowCompression ?
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCompatible :
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCurrent;
                                                  ~
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FileUtils.m:129:30:
    warning: unused variable 'exportError' [-Wunused-variable]
                        NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:2
    25:68: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum
    UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPreset' to different enumeration type 'enum
    DKImageExportPresent' [-Wenum-conversion]
            exportConfiguration.imageExportPreset = allowCompression ?
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCompatible :
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCurrent;
                                                  ~
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                  ~
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:2
    25:124: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum
    UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPreset' to different enumeration type 'enum
    DKImageExportPresent' [-Wenum-conversion]
            exportConfiguration.imageExportPreset = allowCompression ?
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCompatible :
            UIImagePickerControllerImageURLExportPresetCurrent;
                                                  ~
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 warnings generated.
    /* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Storyboards/WebView
    .storyboard:global: warning: This file is set to build for a version older than the deployment
    target. Functionality may be limited. [9]
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan2-4.1.4/ios/Classes/BarcodeScannerView
    Controller.swift:47:38: warning: 'flashMode' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
    AVCapturePhotoSettings.flashMode instead.
        return device != nil && (device?.flashMode == AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode.on ||
        device?.torchMode == .on)
                                         ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan2-4.1.4/ios/Classes/BarcodeScannerView
    Controller.swift:206:14: warning: 'flashMode' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
    AVCapturePhotoSettings.flashMode instead.
          device.flashMode = on ? .on : .off
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan2-4.1.4/ios/Classes/SwiftBarcodeScanPl
    ugin.swift:23:36: warning: 'devices(for:)' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
    AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession instead.
                result(AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: .video).count)
                                       ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan2-4.1.4/ios/Classes/BarcodeScannerView
    Controller.swift:47:38: warning: 'flashMode' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
    AVCapturePhotoSettings.flashMode instead.
        return device != nil && (device?.flashMode == AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode.on ||
        device?.torchMode == .on)
                                         ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan2-4.1.4/ios/Classes/BarcodeScannerView
    Controller.swift:206:14: warning: 'flashMode' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
    AVCapturePhotoSettings.flashMode instead.
          device.flashMode = on ? .on : .off
                 ^
    /Users/niwat/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan2-4.1.4/ios/Classes/SwiftBarcodeScanPl
    ugin.swift:23:36: warning: 'devices(for:)' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use
    AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession instead.
                result(AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: .video).count)
                                       ^
```

There are some flutter null-aware operator warnings and then followed by this:

```
Project /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS built and packaged successfully.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate
    failure
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'SAMKeychain' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/niwat/Flutter_Project_POS/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions
    is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

My build phase script

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/firebase-config"

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

    "bposStaging" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/bposStaging/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    "bposProduction" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/bposProduction/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;
        
    "sabuyStaging" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/sabuyStaging/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;
        
    "sabuyProduction" )
        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/sabuyProduction/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

Flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-arm, locale en-TH)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ✗ Could not determine java version
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google
    Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[!] Connected device
    ! Error: iPad Gen5th is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPad Gen5th is connected. (code
      -13)

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

This happened in both M1 and Intel Mac.
Also, I'm an android developer and I'm not familiar with ios development.

Comment: Any solution yet?